# Mixamo addon not working

Tags: rigging

When I try to use the mixamo addon with my character it gives me this error message.

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/20262059/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.93/scripts/addons/Mixamo add-on for Blender/mixamo_rig.py", line 176, in execute
    _make_rig(self)
  File "/Users/20262059/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.93/scripts/addons/Mixamo add-on for Blender/mixamo_rig.py", line 1902, in _make_rig
    add_leg("Left")
  File "/Users/20262059/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.93/scripts/addons/Mixamo add-on for Blender/mixamo_rig.py", line 1122, in add_leg
    cns = c_foot_ik_pb.constraints.get(cns_name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'constraints'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

This is a character rigged on mixamo and then downloaded in default pose
The character came. out looking like this

[image]

I then tried a character from mixamo. it still did not work. it gave me this error message.

I then tried again with a character from mixamo, this time with an animation. it still had an error code this time with this error message.

```
  File "/Users/20262059/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.93/scripts/addons/Mixamo add-on for Blender/mixamo_rig.py", line 176, in execute
    _make_rig(self)
  File "/Users/20262059/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.93/scripts/addons/Mixamo add-on for Blender/mixamo_rig.py", line 1902, in _make_rig
    add_leg("Left")
  File "/Users/20262059/Library/Application Support/Blender/2.93/scripts/addons/Mixamo add-on for Blender/mixamo_rig.py", line 1122, in add_leg
    cns = c_foot_ik_pb.constraints.get(cns_name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'constraints'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Some characters like Maria W above on the Mixamo site - probably created by an older version - have this issue with the Blender addon. Others like Ninja work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you: weird error messages and a badly mangled armature after running the "Mixamo Rig" add-on.  It just so happens that I had a previous problem with the bone naming conventions supplied by mixamo inside blender. In short, mixamo names it's bones like "mixamorig:Hips" and "mixamorig:RightUpLeg", and blender's naming format is "Hips" and "UpLeg.R" etc.  Certain actions were not applying to certain characters such as "BigVegs" which has bone names like "newVegas:Hips", and apparently certain armature tools won't work until you rename the bones as well.  See [here for more info](https://minapecheux.com/website/2021/09/26/renaming-mixamo-rigs-with-blenders-python-api/).

This may seem like an unrelated problem, but after running the "Mixamo Rig Renamer" I was successfully able to add a control rig -- at least on ybot.  It worked on "Jasper" too, but only if I unchecked "apply animation".  YMMV.

[image]

A picture is worth a thousand words, so in the above screen shot see how after running "mixamo rig renamer", the bones on "Armature" are named "Hips", "UpLeg.R" etc. whereas on "Armature.004" (which I didn't run the renamer on, and thus has the default mixamo names) its "mixamorig:Hips" etc.  After renaming the bones to the blender standard I was then able to successfully run Mixamo's "Create Control Rig".

Yes, this is a hack -- someone really probably needs to open up a bug report on Adobe for a proper solution: but it worked for me, and maybe it will work for you too.

Even if it doesn't fix the problem for you, in my experience it's a good idea to get used to renaming the bones on mixamo imports to blender conventions anyway, since it can cause weird things to happen.  Just be careful about running "Mixamo Rig Renamer" on an existing project because it will rename *all* you rigs -- try it on an experimental blend file, or just make sure it didn't change anything you didn't want before saving on an existing project.

Comment: For me...Oddly Mixamo is having the same problem in Windows 10.
In Linux PoP OS 12, Everything works properly.